# CSS3 Support for Windows Phone 7 IE

Tags: windows-phone-7, css

I would like to know what sort of CSS3 transformation properties are Hardware Accelerated in the latest IE in Windows Phone 7 Mango update. This information seems nowhere to be found.

Comment: I had read that win phone 7 runs ie7.

Comment: @chovy WP7.0 used a version of IE7. Mango uses IE9

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much around this, but I imagine it would only be the computationally intensive transformations if anything: out of the list of CSS3 features supported [mentioned on the IE9 Mobile article here](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/09/22/ie9-mobile-developer-overview.aspx), maybe 2D Transforms?

In any case, why would information on which CSS3 transforms are Hardware Accelerated be useful? It seems kind of weird/counterintuitive to be designing your CSS based on whether it will be accelerated or not?

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. Why wouldn't i want to know which transforms are hardware accelerated so that my site has better performance? It's my job to design mobile sites and usually clients target more than one mobile device.

Comment: Fair enough - but what I'm kind of getting at is that:

1) It feels a bit like premature optimization, especially if you're targeting more than one mobile device where each implementation will be different. 

2) You should probably be selecting CSS3 transforms that fit the purpose - only selecting CSS3 transforms based on which ones are fast or slow probably isn't the right way to go (and you have no control over that anyway)

Grab an actual WP7 device and just test it out, if it performs acceptably, then who really cares if it was accelerated or not? 

Just my two cents :)